# Display minimum value and related field to that value

Tags: php, xml

Php rookie here, i know this should be simple but couldn't make it to work.

I have an xml data (sent by a 3rd party provider) which I want to display into my site. I have already parsed the xml using simplexml.
I could access "Company" in $xml->Outputs->Company.

```
<Company>
    <Name key="1">Company One</Name>
    <Amount_1>20</Amount_1>
    <Amount_2>25</Amount_2>
    <Amount_3>30</Amount_3>
    <Amount_4>40</Amount_4>
</Company>
<Company>
    <Name key="2">Company Two</Name>
    <Amount_1>21</Amount_1>
    <Amount_2>24</Amount_2>
    <Amount_3>17</Amount_3>
    <Amount_4>19</Amount_4>
</Company>
```

What i want to do is to go through "ALL" of the amounts and output the lowest value.

After outputting the lowest value, I need to connect/display the company name which offers that value.

Example:

"Company Two" offers the lowest value with an offer of $"17".

Thank you.

Comment: is there always amount_1, amount_2, amount_3, amount_4? or can there be amount_99 as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `simplexml` and `xpath` to select all amounts, get the lowest, use `xpath` again to retrieve the company-name:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x
$amounts = $xml->xpath("//*[substring(name(),1, 7) = 'Amount_']");
$min = min(array_map('intval', $amounts));
$company = $xml->xpath("//*[substring(name(),1, 7) = 'Amount_' and .='$min']/../Name")[0];
echo "$company offers the article for $min.";
```

Output:

```
Company Two offers the article for 17.
```

Comments:

- line 2: select all nodes starting with `Amount_` and stuff them into `$amounts`  --> BTW, using node names in the way displayed in your XML is terrible. It is much simpler to just use any number of `<amount>`-nodes that you can select easily with xPath because they all have the same name.
- line 3: use `array_map()` to convert items in `$amounts` from `simplexml_objects` into `integers`
- line 3: and use `min()`to save the minimal value into `$min`
- line 4: use `xpath` again to select `Company/Name` having a child `<Amount_*>` with the value `$min`
- line 5: `echo` it.

see it working: https://eval.in/69520